# IOS Universal Link not opening in facebook app

Tags: ios-universal-links, applinks

I want to have my url monkeybrainsapps.com/sudokugame?id=123 open in my app from facebook app. My universal link in ios is properly setup ie when I click on the link from gmail, notes, messages etc, it opens in my app fine. However when I open it from facebook app it just goes to my website and from there gets redirected to app store page for my app.
How to fix it?

Here are screen shots of what happens when I click the link in facebook:
[image: page after I click on link]

but when I click on "open app", it just opens the app store.

I tried implementing facebook's applink infra on server side where I include meta tags in [www.monkeybrainsapps.com](http://www.monkeybrainsapps.com) but that did not change much..

Any ideas?